# Azure Service Bus ReceiveBatch() getting slow over time

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm using retrieving message from Azure Service Bus Topic currently and running into a performance issue. I'm requesting messages in batches of 1000 from ASB. The code fetches anywhere between 200-300 messages in first few iterations and then the number of messages retrieved comes down to 1 per iteration. I pull approximately 50K messages which the application is able to retrieve about 2 hours. Every time I stop the application and re-run it, it behaves the same. First 4-5K records get processed in 1-2 mins, but the rest take lot longer. How can I make my code to retrieve more messages in every batch?

Sample Code with batch size set to 50

```
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
public static  Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SubscriptionClient subscriptionClient;

public async Task startProcess()
{
    await Run();    
}

public async Task Run()
{
    subscriptionClient = Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ServiceBusConnectionString, TopicName, subscriptionname);

     for(int counter=1;counter<= 5;)
     {
                    
           tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PullMessages(counter))) ;
           taskCounter++;
      }
      var arr = tasks.ToArray();
      Task.WaitAll(arr);
    
}

public async Task PullMessages(object ThreadNumber)
{
    bool retry = true;
    do
    {

          subscriptionClient.PrefetchCount = 1000;
          iterationCount++;
          var messages = await subscriptionClient.ReceiveBatchAsync(50);
          logger.Info("{0} messages retrieved for iteration {1} for thread {2}", messages.Count().ToString(), currentiteration.ToString(),ThreadNumber);
          await subscriptionClient.CompleteBatchAsync(messages.Select(m => m.LockToken));
          logger.Info("Completed iteration {0} for thread {1}", currentiteration.ToString(), ThreadNumber);
 
          if (messages != null && messages.Count() > 0)
          {
               retry = true;
          }
          else
          {
               retry = false;
          }
     } while (retry);



}
```

Log:

2020-07-21 19:06:48.3177  Info 50 messages retrieved for iteration 2 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:06:48.3177  Info 50 messages retrieved for iteration 3 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:06:48.3177  Info Completed iteration 4 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:06:48.3177  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 6 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:06:48.3177  Info 50 messages retrieved for iteration 5 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:06:48.3177  Info 50 messages retrieved for iteration 1 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:06:48.6010  Info Completed iteration 3 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:06:48.6010  Info Completed iteration 5 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:06:48.6010  Info Completed iteration 2 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:06:48.6010  Info Completed iteration 6 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:06:48.6225  Info Completed iteration 1 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:06:48.8367  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 7 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:06:49.0683  Info 10 messages retrieved for iteration 8 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:06:49.0934  Info Completed iteration 7 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:06:49.3005  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 9 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:06:49.3491  Info Completed iteration 8 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:06:49.5301  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 10 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:06:49.5612  Info Completed iteration 9 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:06:49.7868  Info Completed iteration 10 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:06:49.7868  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 11 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:06:50.0586  Info Completed iteration 11 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:06:50.2511  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 12 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:06:50.5141  Info Completed iteration 12 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:06:50.5838  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 13 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:06:50.8426  Info Completed iteration 13 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:06:50.9471  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 14 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:06:51.2014  Info Completed iteration 14 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:06:51.2475  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 15 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:06:51.5003  Info Completed iteration 15 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:06:51.6126  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 16 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:06:51.8709  Info Completed iteration 16 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:06:51.9732  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 17 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:06:52.2269  Info Completed iteration 17 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:06:52.3523  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 18 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:06:52.6095  Info Completed iteration 18 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:06:52.7559  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 19 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:06:53.0392  Info Completed iteration 19 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:06:53.1315  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 20 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:06:53.3902  Info Completed iteration 20 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:06:53.4929  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 21 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:06:53.9374  Info Completed iteration 21 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:06:53.9374  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 22 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:06:54.1891  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 23 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:06:54.5142  Info Completed iteration 22 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:06:54.5142  Info Completed iteration 23 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:06:54.5735  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 24 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:06:54.8614  Info Completed iteration 24 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:06:55.0985  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 25 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:06:55.3322  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 26 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:06:55.3994  Info Completed iteration 25 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:06:55.7143  Info Completed iteration 26 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:06:55.7143  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 27 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:06:56.0099  Info Completed iteration 27 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:06:56.3277  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 28 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:06:56.5589  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 29 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:06:56.6247  Info Completed iteration 28 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:06:56.9426  Info Completed iteration 29 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:06:56.9426  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 30 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:06:57.2370  Info Completed iteration 30 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:06:57.2957  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 31 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:06:57.5569  Info Completed iteration 31 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:06:57.6317  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 32 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:06:58.1697  Info Completed iteration 32 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:06:58.1697  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 33 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:06:58.3963  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 34 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:06:58.4675  Info Completed iteration 33 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:06:58.7874  Info Completed iteration 34 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:06:58.7874  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 35 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:06:59.0824  Info Completed iteration 35 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:06:59.1997  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 36 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:06:59.4628  Info Completed iteration 36 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:06:59.5767  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 37 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:06:59.8384  Info Completed iteration 37 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:06:59.9965  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 38 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:07:00.2579  Info Completed iteration 38 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:07:00.4314  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 39 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:07:00.6886  Info Completed iteration 39 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:07:00.7793  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 40 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:07:01.0557  Info Completed iteration 40 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:07:01.1719  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 41 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:07:01.4312  Info Completed iteration 41 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:07:01.5550  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 42 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:07:01.8257  Info Completed iteration 42 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:07:01.9706  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 43 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:07:02.2463  Info Completed iteration 43 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:07:02.3205  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 44 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:07:02.5932  Info Completed iteration 44 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:07:02.6965  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 45 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:07:02.9570  Info Completed iteration 45 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:07:03.0397  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 46 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:07:03.2964  Info Completed iteration 46 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:07:03.4604  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 47 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:07:03.7161  Info Completed iteration 47 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:07:03.8770  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 48 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:07:04.1327  Info Completed iteration 48 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:07:04.2976  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 49 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:07:04.5538  Info Completed iteration 49 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:07:04.6536  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 50 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:07:04.9064  Info Completed iteration 50 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:07:05.0138  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 51 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:07:05.2715  Info Completed iteration 51 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:07:05.3778  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 52 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:07:05.6295  Info Completed iteration 52 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:07:05.7348  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 53 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:07:05.9970  Info Completed iteration 53 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:07:06.1308  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 54 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:07:06.3863  Info Completed iteration 54 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:07:06.4485  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 55 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:07:06.7028  Info Completed iteration 55 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:07:06.8388  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 56 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:07:07.1086  Info Completed iteration 56 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:07:07.2214  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 57 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:07:07.4797  Info Completed iteration 57 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:07:07.6303  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 58 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:07:07.8891  Info Completed iteration 58 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:07:07.9782  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 59 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:07:08.2421  Info Completed iteration 59 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:07:08.3398  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 60 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:07:08.5981  Info Completed iteration 60 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:07:08.8066  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 61 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:07:09.0616  Info Completed iteration 61 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:07:09.2397  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 62 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:07:09.4960  Info Completed iteration 62 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:07:09.6018  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 63 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:07:09.9001  Info Completed iteration 63 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:07:10.0836  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 64 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:07:10.3393  Info Completed iteration 64 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:07:10.4576  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 65 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:07:10.7138  Info Completed iteration 65 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:07:10.8472  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 66 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:07:11.1566  Info Completed iteration 66 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:07:11.2157  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 67 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:07:11.4675  Info Completed iteration 67 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:07:11.5828  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 68 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:07:11.8385  Info Completed iteration 68 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:07:11.9688  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 69 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:07:12.2347  Info Completed iteration 69 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:07:12.3906  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 70 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:07:12.6533  Info Completed iteration 70 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:07:12.6990  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 71 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:07:12.9680  Info Completed iteration 71 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:07:13.1004  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 72 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:07:13.3642  Info Completed iteration 72 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:07:13.4772  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 73 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:07:13.7345  Info Completed iteration 73 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:07:13.8477  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 74 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:07:14.1009  Info Completed iteration 74 for thread 1

2020-07-21 19:07:14.1812  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 75 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:07:14.4479  Info Completed iteration 75 for thread 5

2020-07-21 19:07:14.5517  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 76 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:07:14.8190  Info Completed iteration 76 for thread 2

2020-07-21 19:07:14.9361  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 77 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:07:15.1989  Info Completed iteration 77 for thread 3

2020-07-21 19:07:15.3167  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 78 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:07:15.5961  Info Completed iteration 78 for thread 4

2020-07-21 19:07:15.6242  Info 1 messages retrieved for iteration 79 for thread 1

Comment: You are smashing the thread-pool with a `Parallel.ForEach` over what should be an *IO bound* work load. Learn about the *async and await pattern*, use the `async` version of the azure methods and don't use  `Parallel.ForEach`. Use something that can deal with async, Like `Task.WhenAll` RX, or DataFlow, would be a start. Also stop using the Thread Class

Comment: Also 2. if you find your self needing to do this `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` you can just about guarantee you are doing something wrong. My suggestion is before you try and make this all parallel, try to use the *async and await pattern* properly first, then we can look at making this more efficient

Comment: Aside from the threading concerns, you might need to manually set the `PrefetchCount` in order to increase the message buffer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-prefetch

Comment: @TheGeneral I've changed the code per your suggestion and updated the question with latest. I've also added logs from the service.

First few iterations pull 50 messages  per batch. overtime it comes down to 1 message for every batch

Comment: @devNull : I tried setting PrefetchCount already, it does not seem to have any impact.